# Regular expression grouping with lookaheads (in Python)

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm modifying a regular expression to extract a group of group matches, but this 'supergroup' does not return the composite matched string as expected.

The string to match is of the form:

```
/DIR/SOMESTRING-W0.12+345.raw.gz
```

and the regex I'm using:

```
/DIR/
(?P<super>
    (?P<name>.*?)
    (?=(?P<modifier>-W\d\.\d{2}[+-]\d{3})?\.(?P<extension>raw\.gz|root)$)
)
```

I'm getting the following results for the named groups:

```
modifier: '-W0.12+345'
super: 'SOMESTRING'
name: 'SOMESTRING'
extension: 'raw.gz'
```

while I was expecting

```
super: 'SOMESTRING-W0.12+345.raw.gz'
```

The grouping of subgroups has always worked for me, but not this time, and I cannot understand why.

Hope someone could give me some hint.

NOTE: The explanation of this regex can be found in ([matching a specific substring with regular expressions using awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4450034/matching-a-specific-substring-with-regular-expressions-using-awk))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The group `super` matches the same text that the group `name` matches, because the lookahead assertion doesn't contribute any actual characters to the match (that's why they're also called "zero-width assertions").

To get the desired result, just remove the lookahead assertion:

```
/DIR/
(?P<super>
    (?P<name>.*?)
    (?P<modifier>-W\d\.\d{2}[+-]\d{3})?\.(?P<extension>raw\.gz|root)$
)
```

Comment: Wow, so easy as that! I was under the impression that the lookahead was absolutely necessary. Thanks!